# Help with a problem in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Please help, I cannot figure out how to solve this problem:

A set of positive integers **{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}** is used to form a pack of nine cards.
Each card displays one positive integer without repetition from this set. Grace wishes to select four cards at random from this pack of nine cards.

a)Find the number of selections Grace could make if the largest integer drawn among the four cards is either a **5**, a **6** or a **7**.

b)Find the number of selections Grace could make if at least two of the four integers drawn are even.

Comment: Any thoughts?  to make a selection of four where the highest is $5$ you need to choose three from $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  And so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a)**
If 5 is selected as largest number then we have $4 * 3 * 2$ ways to pick other numbers from $\{1,2,3,4\}$. So we have $1 * 4 * 3 * 2\text{ ways }= 24$.

Similarly for 6, we have $5 * 4 * 3$ ways to pick other numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. So we have $1 * 5 * 4 * 3\text{ ways }= 60.$

Similarly for 7, we have $6 * 5 * 4$ ways to pick other numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. So we have $1 * 6 * 5 * 4\text{ ways }= 120.$

Total ways $= 24 + 60 + 120 = 204.$

**b)**
For even numbers we have $C(4,2)$ and for odd $C(5,2)$. And these 4 numbers can further arrange in $4!$ ways.

So number of ways $= 4 *[ C(4,2) * C(5,2)].$

Answer (score 0):

---

a)

If 7 is the highest integer, the next 3 cards must be one of {1,2,3,4,5,6}, i.e., a combination (a number of possible arrangements when the order does not matter) of 3 cards from the set. $${}_{6}\text{C}_{3}={6\choose 3}=\frac{6!}{3! (6-3)!}=20$$

Next we do the same for the two other integers being the largest.
$$\begin{aligned} {}_{5}\text{C}_{3}&={5\choose 3}=\frac{5!}{3! (5-3)!}=10\\[0.2cm]{}_{4}\text{C}_{3}&={4\choose 3}=\frac{4!}{3! (4-3)!}=4 \end{aligned}$$
The number of selections is then the sum of the three $=34$

---

b)

If at least 2 of the 4 cards must be even, we will have 3 options:

- 2 even, 2 odd
- 3 even, 1 odd
- 4 even

In {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} there are 4 even and 5 odd integers. Therefore, one can think of each of the options as how many combinations of even $and$ odd integers are there.

i.e., 2 even and 2 odd cards can be written as how many combinations/ arrangements of even cards (2 out of 4) there are and multiplying that with the same for the odd cards (2 out of 5)
$${}_{4}\text{C}_{2}\times{}_{5}\text{C}_{2}
={4\choose 2}\times{5\choose 2}
=\frac{4!}{2! (4-2)!}\times\frac{5!}{2! (5-2)!}=6\times 10=60$$

3 even, 1 odd

$${}_{4}\text{C}_{3}\times{}_{5}\text{C}_{1}
={4\choose 3}\times{5\choose 1}
=\frac{4!}{3! (4-3)!}\times\frac{5!}{1! (5-1)!}=4\times 5=20$$

4 even

all of the even cards -> 1 option
(4 of the 4 even cards, and 0 of 5 of the odd ones)
$${}_{4}\text{C}_{4}\times{}_{5}\text{C}_{0}={4\choose 4}\times{5\choose 0}=\frac{4!}{4! (4-4)!}\times\frac{5!}{0! (5-0)!}=1$$

The number of selections: $81$

---